# Parameterized Scheduler in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I switched from declerativ pipeline to scripted pipeline. Everything works fine only  the Parameterized Scheduler Plugin makes problems. If i have one Trigger it works and the pipeline is scheduled. If i add another trigger only the second one works. May be it's a syntax problem but everything i tried doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
properties([ 
    parameters([            
        booleanParam (defaultValue: true, description: 'test', name: 'test')
    ]),
    pipelineTriggers([   
        parameterizedCron('15 20 * * * test=true'),
        parameterizedCron('05 20 * * * test=false')
    ])      
])//properties
```

Answer (score 3):

according to [official documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-scheduler-plugin/blob/master/README.md) your syntax is wrong, you are missing `%`. Also you can use one multiline `parameterizedCron`.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
      string(name: 'PLANET', defaultValue: 'Earth', description: 'Which planet are we on?')
      string(name: 'GREETING', defaultValue: 'Hello', description: 'How shall we greet?')
    }
    triggers {
        cron('* * * * *')
        parameterizedCron('''
# leave spaces where you want them around the parameters. They'll be trimmed.
# we let the build run with the default name
*/2 * * * * %GREETING=Hola;PLANET=Pluto
*/3 * * * * %PLANET=Mars
        ''')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "${GREETING} ${PLANET}"
                script { currentBuild.description = "${GREETING} ${PLANET}" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in your case it should be

```
properties([ 
    parameters([            
        booleanParam (defaultValue: true, description: 'test', name: 'test')
    ]),
    pipelineTriggers([   
        parameterizedCron('''
             15 20 * * * %test=true
             05 20 * * * %test=false''')
    ])      
])//properties
```

Also please note that there's [this open issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49502), which indicates that for your trigger to register for the scripted, it would need to be run manually at least twice.

Comment: Hi, your example is for declerative pipeline. I am working with a scripted pipeline...

Comment: Hi, it´s still the same problem. After running the job a few times only the second trigger is showed in the ui and only the second trigger works. The % seemed not to the problem.

Comment: Ah yes, the original example shows a multiline use as in the updated answer.

Comment: Yes thats it... It got to be multiline with the %.

Comment: Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if the solution worked for you.